# CSS align text left in center div with automatic line break

Tags: css, alignment, centering, text-alignment

There are quite a few answers with very similar topic, but none of it helped me with my problem.

What I'd like is to have is a list of horizontal items (for a menu), where all together are 100% width of the parent (for what I used `flex`).

Text inside the items should break automatically (without `<br />`, I don't know texts in advance) aligned left and then broken box should be in the middle of the item. When hovered (as shown in the example), entire item (including paddings) should change the background color.

Paddings left and right inside the elements should by this method be determined automatically, so that the menu is responsive (on mobile the padding will be 0 and or large screens accordingly bigger).

I've also attached a simplified snippet of the closest thing I got to my desired result. No matter how much I change the html structure or css, I can't left align text when items are centered (this overrides left align).

But I do not care if the result is completely different, as long it will work without without any manual work for every item :).

I'd really appreciate any help! Thanks!

```css
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    ul {
      /* simulate small screen */
      width: 500px;
      display: flex;
      list-style: none;
      background: aqua;
    }

    ul li {
      padding: 10px 0;
      border-left: 1px solid red;
      flex-grow: 1;
      flex-shrink: 1;
      text-align: center;
    }

    ul li div {
      text-align: left;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    ul li:hover {
      background: yellow;
    }
```

```html
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div>Menu Item</div>
      </li>
      
      <li>
        <div>Menu Item Name</div>
      </li>
      
      <li>
        <div>Menu Item</div>
      </li>
      
      <li>
        <div>Menu</div>
      </li>
      
      <li>
        <div>Menu Item</div>
      </li>
      
      <li>
        <div>Menu Item Name</div>
      </li>
      
      <li>
        <div>Menu Item</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Wanted result (forth element is wrong, image was fixed by hand to show the correct result):

[image]

Comment: Do you just want horizontal padding on your `li` elements or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Horizontal padding yes, but I want it to adjust base on the screen size. So on mobile padding will be 0 and the menu will be totally squashed, but on larger screens padding will be accordingly bigger. Added to description.

Comment: Ever tried my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a library such as bootstrap to create a responsive element or you can put your elements within a table which will have a width of the screen and the table will handle positioning and sizing for you.

```
<table style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
        <td>Item 1</td>
        <td>Item 2</td>
        <td>Item 3</td>
        <td>Item 4</td>
    </tr>
<table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/v1f0kz22/3/

Comment: That can also be done, also tried it, but text left aligned text also gets overridden in a table so it's centered.

Comment: Override the table cells text-align property to left.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this answers your questions

CSS

```
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    ul {
      /* simulate small screen */
      width: 500px;
      display: flex;
      list-style: none;
      background: aqua;
    }

    ul li {
      padding: 10px 0;
      border-left: 1px solid red;
      flex-grow: 1;
      flex-shrink: 1;
      text-align: center;
    }

    ul li div {
      text-align: center;
      word-break: normal; // can use break-all for more aggressive style
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    ul li:hover {
      background: yellow;
    }
```

And the HTML

```
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div>Menu Item</div>
      </li>

      <li>
        <div>Menu Item Name</div>
      </li>

      <li>
        <div>Menu Item</div>
      </li>

      <li>
        <div>Menu</div>
      </li>

      <li>
        <div>Menu Item</div>
      </li>

      <li>
        <div>Menu Item Name</div>
      </li>

      <li>
        <div>Menu Item</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Hey! Unfortunately not, but thanks a lot for trying! The problem is that text is now center aligned, not left aligned.

Comment: @JakaKonda: do you want first line to be aligned left and all following lines to be aligned center ??

Comment: No, left inside a `div`, and then div center inside a `li` item.

Answer (score 0):

Try to look about flex-basis , result it's almost like in your picture.

```css
* {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    ul {
      /* simulate small screen */
      width: 500px;
      display: flex;
      list-style: none;
      background: aqua;
    }

    ul li {
      padding: 10px 0;
      border-left: 1px solid red;
      flex-grow: 1;
      flex-shrink: 1;
      // text-align: center;
      justify-content:center;
      display: flex;
    }

    ul li div {
      text-align: left;
      margin: 0 auto;
      flex: 0 0 70%;
    }

    ul li:hover {
      background: yellow;
    }
```

```html
<ul>
      <li>
        <div>Menu Item</div>
      </li>
      
      <li>
        <div>Menu Item Name</div>
      </li>
      
      <li>
        <div>Menu Item</div>
      </li>
      
      <li>
        <div>Menu</div>
      </li>
      
      <li>
        <div>Menu Item</div>
      </li>
      
      <li>
        <div>Menu Item Name</div>
      </li>
      
      <li>
        <div>Menu Item</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be it.

```css
* {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    ul {
      /* simulate small screen */
      width: 500px;
      display: flex;
      list-style: none;
      background: aqua;
    }

    ul li {
      padding: 10px 0;
      border-left: 1px solid red;
      flex-grow: 1;
      flex-shrink: 1;
      text-align: center;
    }

    ul li div {
      text-align: left;
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding-left: 10px;
      padding-right: 10px;
    }

    ul li:hover {
      background: yellow;
    }
```

```html
<ul>
      <li>
        <div>Menu Item</div>
      </li>
      
      <li>
        <div>Menu Item Name</div>
      </li>
      
      <li>
        <div>Menu Item</div>
      </li>
      
      <li>
        <div>Menu</div>
      </li>
      
      <li>
        <div>Menu Item</div>
      </li>
      
      <li>
        <div>Menu Item Name</div>
      </li>
      
      <li>
        <div>Menu Item</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
```